# how to focus on the first tab, when having a few tabs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
 var tabs = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs',
        resizeTabs: true,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 250,
        defaults: {
            autoScroll: true,
            bodyPadding: 10
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1003',
            iconCls: 'tabs',
            //ref:'http://www.yahoo.com',
            //hrefTarget:'_self',
            html: '<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#cccccc;"><iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" frameborder=0  style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe></div>',
            closable: true,
            focusOnToFront  : true
        }],.........................
```

how to focus on the first tab, when having a few tabs?
i use focusOnToFront,but it's seen doesn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'focus'? So it's the active one? Have you looked at the `activeTab` property of `tabpanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you already have your tabpanel defined in the variable `tabs`, if you want to make your first tab visible the easiest way would be this:

```
tabs.setActiveTab(0);
```

As covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `activeTab` property:

```
var tabs = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {  
    activeTab: 0,
    ...
```